# Modify matplotlib TextBox value without triggering callback

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example, I have a `Slider` with a callback set via `on_changed()`. I have the option of modifying the `Slider` value with `set_val()` without triggering the callback by setting `eventson` to `False` before setting the value.

However, if I set `eventson` to `False` for the `TextBox`, then update the value with `set_val()`, the callback `on_submit()` still gets triggered.

The source code for my version of Matplotlib verifies this:

For `TextBox`:

```
def set_val(self, val):
    newval = str(val)
    if self.text == newval:
        return
    self.text = newval
    self.text_disp.remove()
    self.text_disp = self._make_text_disp(self.text)
    self._rendercursor()
    self._notify_change_observers()
    self._notify_submit_observers()
```

For `Slider`:

```
def set_val(self, val):
    """
    Set slider value to *val*

    Parameters
    ----------
    val : float
    """
    xy = self.poly.xy
    xy[2] = val, 1
    xy[3] = val, 0
    self.poly.xy = xy
    self.valtext.set_text(self.valfmt % val)
    if self.drawon:
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
    self.val = val
    if not self.eventson:
        return
    for cid, func in self.observers.items():
        func(val)
```

Is there a preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a dirty solution, but you could ["monkey patch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) the class TextBox to call your own set_val() instead. Unfortunately, I don't know whether this could have unintended consequences.

```
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

def set_val(self, val):
    newval = str(val)
    if self.text == newval:
        return
    self.text = newval
    self.text_disp.remove()
    self.text_disp = self._make_text_disp(self.text)
    self._rendercursor()
    if self.eventson:
        self._notify_change_observers()
        self._notify_submit_observers()

TextBox.set_val = set_val

(...)

tbox1 = TextBox(tax1, 'Text Box 1')
tbox1.on_submit(...)

tbox1.eventson = False
tbox1.set_val('test')
tbox1.eventson = True

plt.show()
```

<strike>Alternatively, for a better, long term solution, you could raise an issue, or do a pull request at [matplotlib's tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues)</strike> Nevermind, I see you already raised an issue.

Comment: Ok. I'll ask the devs to do a pull request and patch the issue... I don't know if doing this for a textbox was intentional or not though, so maybe there's a reason.